# Инкремент при запросе к набору данных SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql

Как наиболее оптимальным способом при запросе на выборку инкрементировать столбцы запрашиваемых данных.

Допустим пользователь ввел запрос: "*Нутбук Dell*", необходимо инкрементировать каждую выведенную позицию для статистики показов.

Comment: Возможно, стоит вынести эту логику в хранимую процедуру, которая будет возвращать запрашиваемые данные и заодно инкрементировать счетчики.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В запросе (select) этого однозначно не сделать. Либо хранимая процедура, что тоже сомнительно, т.к. это выборка, либо поиск реализовывать подпрограммой, а не единственным запросом. На Oracle это реализуется через PL/SQL и nested table.